# How to calculate shortest path between multiple pick and drop destinations

Tags: algorithm, graph, path-finding, shortest

I have a scenario where I have multiple robots, say 2 in this case and they have to pick and drop some items at specified locations as shown in 
[Figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mPrrQ.jpg).

There are two jobs to be done
1) pick up an object from A and drop at B
2) pick up an object from C and drop at D
The possible routes are

A->B-C->D

A->C->B->D

A->C->D->B

C->D->A->B

C->A->D->B

C->A->B->D

I am a beginner in path planning and am finding it difficult to come up with a solution that can work in this case. I can use dikstra and A* etc to find all possible paths but in my case I have a constraint that the destination node cant be reached if the source node for that particular destination node hasnt been visited first.

Comment: [Travelling Salesman Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem)?

Comment: Thanks I will have a look at it.

Comment: If you have several agents taking care of the deliveries, it might be closer to the [vehicule routing problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vehicle_routing_problem) than to the TSP. Check the VRPPD problem in particular.